# How do I include a missing file in SourceTree?

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

I have a folder being tracked in SourceTree with three sub-directories, all with code. SourceTree is picking up on changes in two of them but not the other one, which contains the bulk of my code and currently I haven't been able to push to remote at all. How can I get SourceTree to include/ pick up on the missing folder?

Comment: Is the contents of the folder, or the folder itself in .gitignore?

Answer (score 0):

Under "Workspace" on the left you can go to "File Status" and there you can see all the files in your repo (even the ignored ones) and can stage and commit them.

However, you should really check why your file is being ignored (probably because of `.gitignore`) and fix your configuration if you really need to track that file.